# VS 2010 Code coverage report not showing lines covered

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-coverage

I am using VS 2010. Code coverage report shows blocks covered and their percentage. Is there anyway I can see lines of code covered and their percentage in the report.I opened the report in VS 2010.
Here msdn library says we can see it but only blocks covered data appeared in my report http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667391(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing service pack of Visual Studio 2010. Code Coverage Coloring started working for native c++ project.